# How to remove this extra piece of boot devices?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, uefi, bootloader

Today when trying to install Linux beside my Windows, I found these two extra *boot devices*:

[image: Boot devices menu when F8 is pressed]

I suspected, and entered the UEFI, where I found this:

[image: UEFI Menu]

Then I remembered, once upon a time I had Ubuntu installed. I was not able to boot into Windows so changed the boot order.

But now I want to get rid of it. Is it **deletable/removable**? Because I want to keep things **clean** before installing another system beside current installation of Windows.

Comment: I reinstalled CentOS, it kinda works fine. Now I don't know what to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the entries with [efibootmgr](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/efibootmgr/).

Comment: I think I'll have to install my Linux first?

Comment: You can use Ubuntu Live USB Stick: create it with [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) and use option "Space used to preserve files across reboots (Ubuntu only):" with some MB, then you can install on ubuntu stick efibootmgr.

Comment: You can try [EasyUEFI](http://easyuefi.com), its for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**Another *possible* solution** (depending on your needs) could be to disable them from the BIOS directly. If you go into boot drives, you will see the option to pick the boot order. Select one and expand the list. You should see the list of all possible drives as options **plus** a 'disabled' option. Selecting disabled will remove those drives' ability to boot.